# Minecraft server querier that generates an image of online players

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, minecraft

This little chunk of code is run every 10 seconds on my desktop. It generates a PNG with up to 6 player faces based on the list of online players.

Is there any way for this code to execute faster? Any comments?

Each player has a PNG of their avatar's face with the title: "*username*_face.png" These are pasted into the main image when that player is online.

I wrote this script to compile their faces into a single image for display in a program called conky, allowing me to display the online players as part of my desktop.

```
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer
import os
from PIL import Image

#Query the server and get player names.
server = MinecraftServer("123.123.123.123", 25565)
query = server.query()
nameList = query.players.names


#Sort the list of player names.
nameList.sort()

#Open our temporary file for storing player names.
tempFile = open('server1_previous_players.txt', 'r')
oldNameList = tempFile.read().splitlines()
tempFile.close()

def createImage(players):
    #create a blank transparent image with the dimensions: 212x147px.
    baseImage = Image.new("RGBA", (212, 147))
    slotList = [(17, 17), (82, 17), (147, 17), (17, 82), (82, 82), (147, 82)]

    if len(players) > 0:
        for x in range(0, 6):
            try:
                face = Image.open(str(nameList[x]).lower() + "_face.png", 'r')
                baseImage.paste(face, slotList[x])
            except:
                break

    baseImage.save("server1_online.png")

#If nothing changed, pass!
if nameList == oldNameList:
    print("same thing!")
    pass

#Else, if no-one is on, but the text file says people are on, empty the text file.
elif len(nameList) == 0 and len(oldNameList) > 0:
    print("everyone left :'(")
    tempFile = open('server1_previous_players.txt', 'w')
    createImage(nameList)

#Else, if at least 1 person is on, generate a new image accordingly.
elif len(nameList) > 0:
    tempFile = open('server1_previous_players.txt', 'w')
    print('\n'.join(nameList), file=tempFile)
    createImage(nameList)

else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [@ovs answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153766/98493). I would use the `for` loop approach (it is almost always nicer in Python, unless you do an infinite `while True` loop.

```
def create_image(players):
    # create a blank transparent image with the dimensions: 212x147px.
    base_image = Image.new("RGBA", (212, 147))
    slot_list = [(17, 17), (82, 17), (147, 17), (17, 82), (82, 82), (147, 82)]

    for slot, player in zip(slot_list, players):
        with Image.open("{}_face.png".format(player.lower())) as face:
            base_image.paste(face, slot)
    base_image.save("server1_online.png")
```

This works, because if `players` is shorter than 6 elements, `zip` will stop there. If it is longer than 6 elements it will stop after `slot_list` is empty, which is exactly 6 elements long.

Here I also changed the names to conform with Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), as well as used `with open(...) as` to ensure the file is closed again. Also note that `"r"` is the default mode of `open`.

The same can be done for the second part. We can also use the fact that empty lists are falsey, so evaluate as `False` in an `if` context:

```
if name_list == old_name_list:
    # nothing changed, pass!
    print("same thing!")
else:
    # generate image and write new player list to file
    if not name_list and old_name_list:
        print("everybody left")
    with open('server1_previous_players.txt', 'w') as temp:
        # writes "" for an empty player list
        temp.write('\n'.join(name_list))  
    create_image(name_list)
```

Comment: Your improvements to the readability and structure of the code are both intuitive and robust. Thank you, I actually gained some FPS while on my server!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will not increase the performance, but I have some general tips:
Use `while` loops instead of `for`-loops with `break`. It will make your code more readable.
I have rewritten the `createImage` function for you:

```
def createImage(players):
    # create a blank transparent image with the dimensions: 212x147px.
    baseImage = Image.new("RGBA", (212, 147))
    slotList = [(17, 17), (82, 17), (147, 17), (17, 82), (82, 82), (147, 82)]

    x = 0
    while x < len(players) and x < 6:
        face = Image.open(str(players[x]).lower() + "_face.png", 'r')
        baseImage.paste(face, slotList[x])
        x += 1
    baseImage.save("server1_online.png")
```

If you prefer `for` over `while`, you can use:

```
def createImage(players):
    # create a blank transparent image with the dimensions: 212x147px.
    baseImage = Image.new("RGBA", (212, 147))
    slotList = [(17, 17), (82, 17), (147, 17), (17, 82), (82, 82), (147, 82)]

    for slot, player in zip(slotList, players):
        face = Image.open(str(player).lower() + "_face.png", 'r')
        baseImage.paste(face, slot)
    baseImage.save("server1_online.png")
```

Read more about `zip` [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip)

You need to close the files you open:

```
# If nothing changed, pass!
if nameList == oldNameList:
    print("same thing!")

# Else, if no-one is on, but the text file says people are on, empty the text file.
elif len(nameList) == 0 and len(oldNameList) > 0:
    print("everyone left :'(")
    tempFile = open('server1_previous_players.txt', 'w')
    tempFile.write("")
    tempFile.close()
    createImage(nameList)

# Else, if at least 1 person is on, generate a new image accordingly.
elif len(nameList) > 0:
    tempFile = open('server1_previous_players.txt', 'w')
    # write should be used instead of print
    tempFile.write('\n'.join(nameList))
    tempFile.close()
    createImage(nameList)
```

An `if`-statement can be used without an else, so if there is only pass in there you don't need it.

If you want to create an empty / transparent image when nobody is on, you can combine both `elif`-statements:

```
# If nothing changed, pass!
if nameList == oldNameList:
    print("same thing!")


# else generate image and write new player list to file
else:
    if len(nameList) == 0 and len(oldNameList) > 0:
        print("everybody left")
    tempFile = open('server1_previous_players.txt', 'w')
    tempFile.write('\n'.join(nameList))  # writes "" for an empty player list
    tempFile.close()
    createImage(nameList)
```

Comment: For me, the `while` loop in Python never feels right unless it is `while True:` :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I modified my code to close the files as I forgot to do that initially.